deptrac show invalid results on violation in hexagonal architecture
I've introduced for my first time hexagonal architecture and I want to other developers keep this principal so I've tried to add deptrac - below my config:
deptrac:
  paths:
    - './src/'
  exclude_files:
    - '#.*[tT]est.php#'
    - '#Kernel\.php$#'
    - '#.*Response.php$#'
  layers:
    - name: Domain
      collectors:
        - type: directory
          value: src/Domain/.*
    - name: Application
      collectors:
        - type: directory
          value: src/Application/.*
    - name: Infrastructure
      collectors:
        - type: directory
          value: src/Infrastructure/.*
    - name: UI
      collectors:
        - type: directory
          value: src/UI/.*
    - name: Shared
      collectors:
        - type: directory
          value: src/Shared/.*
    - name: Symfony
      collectors:
        - type: composer
          composerPath: composer.json
          composerLockPath: composer.lock
          packages:
            - symfony/amqp-messenger
            - symfony/apache-pack
            - symfony/asset
            - symfony/console
            - symfony/doctrine-messenger
            - symfony/dotenv
            - symfony/expression-language
            - symfony/flex
            - symfony/form
            - symfony/framework-bundle
            - symfony/http-client
            - symfony/intl
            - symfony/mailer
            - symfony/mime
            - symfony/monolog-bundle
            - symfony/notifier
            - symfony/process
            - symfony/property-access
            - symfony/property-info
            - symfony/proxy-manager-bridge
            - symfony/runtime
            - symfony/security-bundle
            - symfony/serializer
            - symfony/string
            - symfony/translation
            - symfony/twig-bundle
            - symfony/uid
            - symfony/validator
            - symfony/web-link
            - symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
            - symfony/yaml
    - name: SymfonyValidator
      collectors:
        - type: attribute
          value: 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank'
  ruleset:
    Shared:
      - Symfony
    Domain:
      - Shared
    Application:
      - Domain
      - Shared
      # TODO: Symfony are ONLY allowed in the Application layer cause we use DTOs and Symfony Validator which violates the ruleset, need to allow ONLY for this package
#      - Symfony
      - SymfonyValidator
    Infrastructure:
      - Application
      - Domain
      - Shared
      - Symfony
      - UI
    UI:
      - Infrastructure
      - Application
      - Domain
      - Shared
      - Symfony
  formatters:
    graphviz:
      hidden_layers:
        - Symfony

But every time - even if I add to Domain class ie. Post infra class should throw violation - not happens, I can't debug why - -vvv doesn't show anything useful.
Graphviz also drawn an white square - can anyone help me? This should work, but why doesn't work?
Thanks for any tip how to work with deptrac to keep architecture clean.
Best regards from Poland,
Grzegorz

PS. Issue fixed - I've edited corrected config to the post.
